# How to lookup for a single value in two different datasets that have two columns in common (based on a condition)

Tags: r, match, lookup, matching

I have two different datasets as follows:
[image]

I need to add the call volume, put volume, and total volume columns in dataset #2 if and only if: Both ID and Date columns in both datasets match. I am separating calls, puts, and totals, based on the values in column 3 in dataset #1 (C for calls, P for puts, and T for total).

I am running this code but it isn't working (showing an example of calls only, same rule applies for puts and totals).

```r
dataset2$call_volume <- if(dataset1$optiontype== "C")
{ dataset1$volume [ match (
                          interaction(dataset2$ID,dataset2$date),
                          interaction(dataset1$ID,dataset1$date)
                                         )]}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I could proceed with the code? Many thanks!

```
> dput(dataset1)
structure(list(ID = c(44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266, 
44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266), date = c("1997/01/02", 
"1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", 
"1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", 
"1997/01/03"), `option type (C,P,T: for calls, puts, and total)` = c("C", 
"P", "T", "C", "P", "T", "C", "P", "T", "C", "P", "T"), volume = c(34, 
250, 284, 30, 0, 30, 1443, 211, 1654, 4490, 826, 5316)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(dataset2)
structure(list(ID = c(44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266
), date = c("1997/01/02", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/04", "1997/01/02", 
"1997/01/03", "1997/01/04"), `call volume` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `put volume` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `total volume` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Update: I have many other columns in both datasets that are quite different from one another, the only common are the ones shown in the picture and dataset below.

Comment: Hi Ala. You haven't shown us your data. You have shown us a _picture_ of your data. For anyone to demonstrate a working solution, they would have to transcribe the picture into text. Could you please edit your question (using the gray "edit" link beneath your question) to include data that folks here can use? You can type `dput(dataset1)` and `dput(dataset2)` into the console, then paste the results into your question. Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you Allan, done. I hope it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bit of an x/y problem. I figure you are actually trying to pivot `dataset1` into wide format to populate `dataset2`. After this you can `left_join` the two frames.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

names(dataset1)[3] <- "option_type"

dataset2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(-`call volume`, -`put volume`, -`total volume`) %>%
  left_join(dataset1 %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "option_type", values_from = "volume") %>%
  rename("Call Volume" = C, "Put Volume" = P, "Total Volume" = `T`),
  by = c("ID", "date"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      ID date       `Call Volume` `Put Volume` `Total Volume`
#>   <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 44652 1997/01/02            34          250            284
#> 2 44652 1997/01/03          1443          211           1654
#> 3 44652 1997/01/04            NA           NA             NA
#> 4 56266 1997/01/02            30            0             30
#> 5 56266 1997/01/03          4490          826           5316
#> 6 56266 1997/01/04            NA           NA             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Allan Cameron. The code works well. However, I did not mention in the post that dataset 2 contains many other columns not shared with dataset 1 (and vice versa). Is there a way to do this by keeping those columns as is? Thank you

Comment: @AlaB in that case you need to `left_join` the wide format dataset1 to dataset2 (after removing the empty NA columns). Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want dataset2 with values from dataset1 if it matches or NA if no match.

If that is the case, you need to use `left_join`.

If not, please update you question with desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- structure(list(ID = c(44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266, 
                            44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266), date = c("1997/01/02", 
                                                                                "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", "1997/01/02", 
                                                                                "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/03", 
                                                                                "1997/01/03"), `option type (C,P,T: for calls, puts, and total)` = c("C", 
                                                                                                                                                     "P", "T", "C", "P", "T", "C", "P", "T", "C", "P", "T"), volume = c(34, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        250, 284, 30, 0, 30, 1443, 211, 1654, 4490, 826, 5316)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


d2 <- structure(list(ID = c(44652, 44652, 44652, 56266, 56266, 56266
), date = c("1997/01/02", "1997/01/03", "1997/01/04", "1997/01/02", 
            "1997/01/03", "1997/01/04"), `call volume` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                           NA, NA), `put volume` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `total volume` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))

d1_longer <- d1 %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `option type (C,P,T: for calls, puts, and total)`, values_from = volume) %>%
  rename(`call volume` = `C`, `put volume` = `P`, `total volume` = `T`)

d2 %>%
  select(ID, date) %>%
  left_join(d1_longer)
#> Joining, by = c("ID", "date")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      ID date       `call volume` `put volume` `total volume`
#>   <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 44652 1997/01/02            34          250            284
#> 2 44652 1997/01/03          1443          211           1654
#> 3 44652 1997/01/04            NA           NA             NA
#> 4 56266 1997/01/02            30            0             30
#> 5 56266 1997/01/03          4490          826           5316
#> 6 56266 1997/01/04            NA           NA             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Icaro Bombonato. This works well too! My bad i did not mention that I have other columns in datasets 1 and 2 which are not shared amongst the two.